Has anyone tried to work gravity formulas based on energies instead of mass?
If Adam Reiss, 2011 Nobel Prize winner says negative mass must exist in our universe and published this in his Nobel winning paper, then why is mainstream science not on board?
He not only shows that it's negative mass that is causing the reverse effects, but they also determined space was expanding due to this. Link posted below. I also still did not receive an answer to my question. Has anyone tried to work gravity formulas based on energies instead of mass?
https://www.nobelprize.org/mediaplayer/?id=1729

Can you please report here exactly what he is saying that you interpret as "negative mass must exist"?

At 11:38 in the video, he states when he evaluated the mass of the universe, he came to the conclusion that it was negative value and then goes on to proof that space is expanding based on this information, at 12:08 in the video he clearly states that negative mass must exist. Watch it for yourself.

At 12:08 he explains that negative mass must exist. Then at 12:45 he says that they examined the accuracy and came to 99.73%

@user451224 He does not say any of that. He says the negative mass came as a consequence of his assumption of a zero cosmological constant, and since mass cannot be negative he came to the conclusion that the cosmological constant is nonzero

Have you listen to the sentence that starts at 12:12? "The real reason..."

He even says that negative mass is nonsensical and unphysical so basically the moderator's comment was correct

You should have watched the entire video, at 16:18 he talks about publishing the paper showing that 70% of the universe is dark energy and the cosmological constant shows this and dark energy or negative mass- whatever you want to name it

@user451224 dark energy does not imply negative mass, maybe that's what you are confused about

You also claim that mass cannot be negative, yet the GR and the math show it's possible, not proven at this point. Also physicists' create negative stable mass in the labhttps://phys.org/news/2017-04-physicists-negative-mass.html

@user451224 I didn't claim that, the speaker in the link you posted did

The question body does not seem to ask the same question as the question title. I see in a comment that you wish to ask about energy approaches to gravitational problems, so it might make the question clearer if you edit the question to focus on that, or that the question at least clearly relates the question of negative mass to the actual question.

I would advise you to look more into the article from phys.org you linked. Its presentation is somewhat misleading. When you look at the abstract of the actual paper, they immediately mention "negative effective mass", which is a well-known phenomenon in fields like solid-state physics and not the same as actual negative mass.

Has anyone tried to work gravity formulas based on energies instead of mass? Yes. Einstein. Over a century ago! If you study General Relativity you’ll learn about them. The antigravity of dark energy is not due to negative mass or negative energy but rather to negative pressure. This is a surprising non-Newtonian feature of GR.


He not only shows that it's negative mass that is causing the reverse effects, but they also determined space was expanding due to this.

This is untrue. He explicitly wrote in his slides “There cannot be negative mass” (timestamp 12:35). What he discovered was evidence for a cosmological constant, which he was careful to distinguish from negative mass. He calls the cosmological constant “the other way” (12:20) to have accelerating expansion besides a negative mass.
Also, he was clear that space is not expanding due to the cosmological constant. The cosmological constant leads specifically to an acceleration of the expansion.

Has anyone tried to work gravity formulas based on energies instead of mass?

That is already the case in General Relativity. The source of gravity is the stress-energy tensor. This includes energy density, momentum density, pressure, and stress. Not specifically mass.

The cosmological constant is just another name for dark energy, and dark energy is reverse in gravity than Newton's laws. These are observed with black holes

I was just looking for an answer to whether anyone considered using energies instead of mass to calculate gravity, since every gravity formula is wrong, close but not exact at our scale, and doesn't work at quantum levels. That means the formulas are wrong and we don't understand gravity. I was not looking to argue over negative mass/dark energy.

Dark energy and cosmological constant are synonyms with each other. Neither of them is a synonym for negative mass. If you didn’t want correction about a false statement then you shouldn’t have made it. GR already calculates gravity using energy density among other things (stress energy tensor)

If gravity can exist without mass, as stated by scientists, see link, then how can we use mass to calualte gravity when mass is not needed?https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/technology/gravity-can-exist-without-mass-and-dark-matter-could-be-myth-says-study/ar-AA1s9zw3?ocid=entnewsntp&pc=U531&cvid=9f05657d99ae41aca1de734dbd20658a&ei=11

See my updated answer.

While I understand your answer, every math formula for calculating gravity uses mass and it does not work exact. Should we ignore that they don't work for another 100 years?

You said “every math formula for calculating gravity uses mass and it does not work exact”. This is false. You keep making false statements. There is no mass anywhere in $G_{\mu\nu}+\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}=\kappa T_{\mu\nu}$. Energy is a component of $T$, but not mass. It is difficult to even define mass in GR except in specific cases

Your right negative mass doesn't exist that's why NASA is building a negative mass engine? Straight from NASAhttps://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20200000366/downloads/20200000366.pdf

It doesn't say that NASA is building one. There is indeed literature about the theory, which is all that the .pdf is discussing. Note that in Forward's actual paper https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/10.2514/3.23219 he specifically says "they have enough logical validity that they can be used in writing science fiction" and "I define negative matter as a hypothetical form of matter" and "the experimental fact of its non-existence". It is yet another false statement for you to say that "NASA is building a negative mass engine". Repeating falsehoods may be viable politics, but not science

Also, please stop removing the parts of your question that I specifically quoted. It is disruptive and against the site policy and I will just keep reverting it back to the last version that contains the quoted material.
